# How to run this simple VAR (VARX?) model in matlab, using vgxvarx?

Tags: matlab

Basically, I want to run a VAR model (bivariate) with a linear time trend, and a constant. That is, I was to estimate an equation of the form (pardon the poor notation, but no mathjax here I believe, and I feel equations are easier than words)

```
    [x_t y_t]'= [c_1 c_2]' + [p_1^1 p_2^1 ; p_1^2 p_2^2]* [x_{t-1} y_{t-1}]' +
      + [g^x g^y]'*t + [e^x e^y]
```

where the `e`'s are error terms (white noise), the `g`'s are "gammas", that is constants on the time trend, the `c`'s are constant, and the `{t-1}` terms are lagged, and the matrix they are multiplied by are coefficients on the lags.

My problem, or at least what I cannot seem to figure out, is how to implement the `[g^x g^y]'*t` term. This is because, if I specify `t` as part of the time series, the vgxvarx, then a lag term for `t` will be included, which is not what I want. However, **if I include `t` as exogenous data, then matlab gives me a (1x1) matrix of coefficients, `b`. However, I am looking for a (2x1) vector of coefficients**...

That is, matlab seems to implement the exogenous data as `X_t * b` where `X_t` is (n x r) and `b` is a vector of regression coefficients of size `r`.

I realize that I can estimate this equation using `mvregress`, which I have done. However, I am curious about whether it is possible to estimate the equation using vgxvarx?

Thank you.

Edit: To perhaps slightly elaborate on my issue: the specification I wish to estimate has `[g^x g^y]'*t`, where `g^x` `g^y` are coefficients I need to be estimate, and `y`, which is just the current time period, is an input (a regressor). Matlab, however, when given exogenous data for vgxvarx, estimates `X_t *b`, which is giving me trouble (I need to have `X_t` have at least two dimensions, for one thing, but `t` is one dimensional in the specification. Even if I say okay, let `X_t` be two-dimensional, the `b` is one dimensional, when I want a (2 x 1) vector of coefficients...)

Edit2: Some helpful links:

[Matlab page on VAR models](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/introduction-to-vector-autoregressive-var-models.html)
[Econometrics toolbox pdf.](http://cn.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/econ/econ.pdf) 3-37 has an example I find somewhat similar. I will put some of the relevant code below:

```
        tcell = cell(1000,1); % Time as exogenous input
        for i=1:1000
              tcell{i} = [i;0];
        end
```

As the snippet of code shows, they are included "Time as exogenous input", but again it is 2-dimensional, which is not what I want.

Edit 3: **I have not tried re-working the equation** to try and write it without the `*t` term. Perhaps that is the solution. If so, I don't need the math worked out, but please let me know if that is the only (or only viable way) to estimate the equation using vgxvarx

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `vgxvarx` function in Matlab, but there is no need to include _t_ in your equation. That is, the 2 _g_ parameters are, by themselves, drift terms in that they indicate how much to add/subtract to _x_ and _y_ each time step. Also note that including both the drift terms and the 2x2 matrix **P** indicates you'd like to have a stationary model with no overall trend. If you'd prefer a random walk VAR with only the drift/bias terms, then you need to include the vec **g**, but set **P** to the identity matrix **I**.

Comment: the g parameters are constants though; that is, they do not vary with time? Are they still drift terms then? Because without the *t* they are basically a second additive constant...?

Comment: Yes, the **g** elements are constant, and they would be non-identifiable from the elements in **c**. Also, as I mentioned, the inclusion of the **P** matrix with the diagonal elements < |1| will be stationary (mean-reverting) and therefore won't have any drift/bias.

Comment: Alright, Thank you very much. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:
http://www.mathworks.com/examples/econometrics/mw/econ-ex99989579-simulate-responses-of-estimated-varx-model

in a nut shell

```
EstY = [yourData];   % In-sample responses
estX = [eXogenous];  % In-sample exogenous
n = size(EstY,2);    % num. of Series 

% **** MAYBE THIS IS WHAT YOU ARE LOOKING FOR ****

EstExpandX = kron(estX,eye(n));
EstCellX = mat2cell(EstExpandX,n*ones(estT,1));
nX = size(EstExpandX,2);

% *******************************


% Estimate the model

 Mdl = vgxset('n',n,'nAR',4,'nX',nX,'Constant',true);


 EstMdl = vgxvarx(Mdl,EstY,EstCellX);

 vgxdisp(EstMdl)
```